# facebook authorization error (fandjango)

Tags: python, django, facebook, authorization, fandjango

I'm trying to make my first facebook tab app with django.

I did some resarch and found out that fandjago is the best.

So I'm using it , but when I try to require users to authorize I use the decorator

```
facebook_authorization_required
```

see : https://fandjango.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/authorization.html

I get the following error :

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application     configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}
```

with this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?scope=publish_stream%2C+publish_actions%2C+user_photos&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FWissals-testing%2F368147096656989%3Fid%3D368147096656989%26sk%3Dapp_269443246412431&client_id=269443246412431
```

This is my redirect uri  :

```
facebook_redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/pages/mypage-testing/36814709662989?id=36814709686989&sk=app_26944328962431"
```

Please tell me what I am  doing wrong, I searched all topics related to th eissu but couldn't figure it out

**EDITED**

It worked,I had to add my url in my app configuration "Valid OAuth redirect URIs"
But the problem now is that it gets me out of my app to that url, although I need it to stay on the app!!

Comment: are you building an app on facebook or just want to oauth with facebook?

Comment: You didn't specified the app domain, if your page is hosted on something like this www.mydomain.com/myapps/facebookapp/greatapp you just need to put this "mydomain.com"

Comment: My add is hosted in mydomain.com directly, I alredy tried to add it but it didnt work

Comment: Then why do you have a Website tab if you're building an facebook app?

Comment: was just testing, I removed that

Comment: and same error persist after removing?

Comment: It seems it a problem with my redirect_uri , But I'm not sure what to put in it, plz see my adited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finlly solved it

I had to add the same url of my facebook_redirect_uri to my app settings in facebook, advanced tab, field named : **Valid OAuth redirect URIs**

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a guess here,

you might need to set FANDJANGO_AUTHORIZATION_DENIED_VIEW to fully contain your canvas url

Comment: It seems it a problem with my redirect_uri , But I'm not sure what to put in it, plz see my edited question

Answer (score 1):

The URL to redirect to after the user clicks a button in the dialog. **The URL you specify must be a URL of with the same Base Domain as specified in your app's settings**,

A Canvas URL of the form

```
https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE
```

or a Page Tab URL of the form

```
https://www.facebook.com/PAGE_USERNAME/app_YOUR_APP_ID
```